# CSS tabs won't work as links

Tags: css

here is the site i am having problems with
http://www.iaddesign.com/avola

when i try to click on the tabs it wont work. i have a hover affect with css and cant figure out how to make the tabs work.

let me know thanks.

Answer (score 8):

The link ( `<a>` ) tags within your `li`'s need to have `display:block` to make use of the width and height rules. I just made the modification in firebug and it fixed the problem.

```
#navigation li a 
{ 
  display:block; 
}
```

Furthermore, I would suggest putting your links in the following format:

```
<li>
  <a href="index.php"><span>Index</span></a>
</li>
```

Then hide the inner spans from the visual-rendering:

```
#navigation li a span 
{ 
  display:none; /* or position:absolute; top:-2000px; */
}
```

This way, your navigation is still usable when CSS is disabled.

Comment: display:none; might be ignored by search engines, better use 
#navigation a span {
position:absolute;
top:-2000px;
}

Answer (score 1):

While Jonathan is correct, you might also consider adding invisible `<span>`s inside the `<a>`tags for accesibility.

Answer (score 1):

Jonathan is right. Here's my additional 2 cents.

Your tab has the markup as:

```
<li id="home"><a href="index.php" title=""></a></li>
```

The default display behaviour for `<a>` is `inline`, which coupled with the empty content between the opening and closing tag for `<a>` meant that nothing is rendered visibly on the browser.

Answer (score 0):

you also might want to put the backgrounds on the a elements (if you are supporting ie6) to avoid having to use javascript hacks to support :hover on non-a elements.